# PHP PDO can't get json value in database

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

i'm try to use pdo to get the value was stored in database.
But don't know why the value seem's can't echo it.

Here's my code:

```
    $_GET['id']='138b39bbef558cf44b3d222a6fb4d6b6';
        $query3 = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, MAX(time),answer FROM `answer` where nodes_uuid = :nodeuuid and user_id = 101");
        $query3->bindValue(':nodeuuid', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $query3->execute(); 
$questionCorrectAnswer = $query3->fetch(); 
        echo $questionCorrectAnswer['answer'];
```

table:

```
    id         MAX(time)                  answer
----------    -------------------        ------------ 
    40        2015-02-25 18:18:53        [{"topicId":"1590","ans":["6032"]},"topicId":"1593","ans":["8122"]},{"topicId":"1598","ans":["6064"]},{"topicId":"1601","ans":["6073"]}]
```

Comment: Always [turn on error reporting](https://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/). You might at least get a `Warning: undefined index 'answer'` message. `PDOStatement::fetch()` returns `false` on error, countercheck that with `!==`.

Comment: What does xdebug or a var_dump tells about `$questionCorrectAnswer['answer']` ?

Comment: What is the value of `$conn`?

Comment: @TheCodesee $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mydb", $username, $password);

Comment: @LiouJay Is any result displayed? Have you turned on error reporting?

Comment: @ceadreak here's var_dump result:
array(6) { ["id"]=> NULL [0]=> NULL ["MAX(time)"]=> NULL [1]=> NULL ["answer"]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }

Comment: @DanFromGermany i following the website add those code seem's doesn't print any error message.

Comment: Can you show the result of "SELECT * FROM answer WHERE id = 40"?

Answer (score 1):

The result of:

```
array(6) { ["id"]=> NULL [0]=> NULL ["MAX(time)"]=> NULL [1]=> NULL ["answer"]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }
```

that you are getting indicates your query returned no records.  In an ordinary query, you would get an empty set, however, **because you are using an aggregate function, you are getting all nulls when no records are selected by the query.** The issue here is that your WHERE clause is likely eliminating all records in the table.

Comment: thx,ur comment.but the data was in database.
before i post this question i was check my database.

Comment: @LiouJay This may be the case, but does the combination of nodes_uuid='138b39bbef558cf44b3d222a6fb4d6b6' and user_id=101 occur on the same record?

Comment: Yes ,the result are same.

Comment: @deceze, because he has an aggregate function in his query, he will get all nulls.

Comment: @jpheldson Of course, good catch... You should clarify that in your answer.

Comment: @deceze, thanks for the advice.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think what is wrong here is you are getting an undefined index error. You could try swapping:

```
$questionCorrectAnswer = $query3->fetch();
```

For

```
$questionCorrectAnswer = $query3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

And instead of

`questionCorrectAnswer['answer'];`

I would suggest trying

`questionCorrectAnswer->answer;`

Also as you are storing a Json object it may pay off Print_r($foo) or Var_Dump($foo) just incase there is a Array to String conversion fail going on.

Comment: Or use `$query3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` with`$questionCorrectAnswer['answer']`

Comment: True that, I just prefer -> over [''], I just think its much prettier. It won't work anyway now we've seen his Var Dump is empty.

Comment: @Andrew the result was like below:
array(3) { ["id"]=> NULL ["MAX(time)"]=> NULL ["answer"]=> NULL }

Comment: Result exists and it is right associative array - it means that query was successfully executed and fetched. But values in array are not as expected. Seems like problem is in query `WHERE`, because wrong row was selected.